# error while running sudo apt-get update, E: dpkg was interrupted

Tags: apt, upgrade, updates, dpkg, lts

When I run *sudo apt-get update* or *sudo apt-get upgrade* this error appears

```
E: dpkg was interrupted, you must manually run 'sudo dpkg --configure -a' to correct the problem.
```

and when I run *sudo dpkg --configure -a*, the laptop restarts and freezes at startup when the Ubuntu word is displayed, I just force close it by the power button and then reopen it.

I use Ubuntu 14.04 LTS dual booted with windows 8.1.

Comment: What was the last package you remember installing? The lastest ones will be on the bottom of the output from `grep " install " /var/log/dpkg.log`.

Comment: @AshharHasan nothing appeared

Comment: That's odd. What was the last software you remember installing? Try the answer below and report back with results.

Comment: @AshharHasan here is a picture of the output

Comment: https://plus.google.com/+AhmedEssamFakharany/posts/fANptu73xow

Comment: Try this `cat /var/log/apt/term.log`

Comment: @AshharHasan no output, just like grep " install " /var/log/dpkg.log

Answer (score 1):

Try this on terminal to remove all

```
cd /var/lib/dpkg/updates
sudo rm *
```

And then run the below command to get newer ones,

```
sudo apt-get update
```

Comment: apt-get mostly fails with the same error unless you manually specify which packages to clean and remove.

Comment: By default it's up to system to decide which packages to be removed.

Comment: the same error appeared when I ran both orders 
    E: dpkg was interrupted, you must manually run 'sudo dpkg --configure -a' to correct the problem.

Comment: @RiashatRafat  here is a picture of the output

Comment: https://plus.google.com/+AhmedEssamFakharany/posts/fANptu73xow

Comment: You were trying to install Flash plugins?

Comment: Beat me to it. Also add this: `sudo rm -r /var/lib/dpkg/available` if the above does not work. This will require a system reboot to take proper effect.